# How do I make Notepad++ delete lines like Eclipse does?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Eclipse has a keyboard shortcut which deletes either the current line (if nothing is selected) or all lines which are part of the currently selected text: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Is there a way to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> do the same thing in Notepad++?

The best I could do is remap the shortcut to Scintilla's `SCI_LINE_DELETE`, but that only deletes one line at a time, even if the selection spans multiple lines.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will achieve the same effect.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will delete the line but will also keep it in your clipboard replacing clipboard contents.

I'm not sure if you can map Ctrl+D to do the same thing or not. I've not really messed with the keyboard mappings with Notepad++ since they are very similar to those of Visual Studio

Comment: Brilliant! Now I just have to find what `Ctrl+L` is mapped to ... ***edit*** aha, it's mapped to `SCI_LINECUT`. That was literally the next Scintilla command below `SCI_LINE_DELETE`.

Comment: Please note that `Ctrl+L` will cut the line (copy it into your clipboard). To actually delete the line is `Ctrl+Shift+L`, this will delete the selected lines without overwriting your clipboard.

Comment: @RØŠÐÎ `SCI_LINEDELETE` is what `Ctrl+Shift+L` was mapped to.  I tried that but it only deleted (without copying to clipboard) the first of the selected lines, similar to OP.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Why isn't this in the menu `Edit > Line Operations`

Answer (score 26):

I had to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to **both** `SCI_LINEDELETE` and `SCI_LINECUT` in order to make it behave like Eclipse. Hope this is helpful.

You also need to disable or rebind `SCI_SELECTIONDUPLICATE` so there's no conflict on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
To disable a shortcut, highlight it, click `Modify` set the DropDownList to `None`, click `Apply` first and then `Okay`.

Comment: How come both were required?

Comment: When I map the same shortcut to both of those all that happens is it switches from deleting only the first line of the selected lines to deleting only the line the cursor was on. (I used Ctrl+Shift+D, so I didn't have to worry about the selection duplicate binding.)

Answer (score 16):

Macro is a good choice here. Though the macro I came up with lags a bit (you can see may be quarter of a second lag between CTRL-D hit and lines getting deleted on a large selections) it works grand both on a single line and multiple lines selection and covers various tricky cases.

So, my macro is:

**CTRL + J** - if multiple lines are selected they are joined into a single line 
**HOME** - the usual HOME button. Brings cursor to the start of a line (or start of a joined line) 
**SHIFT + END** - selects the line till the end starting from the cursor position 
**CTRL + SHIFT + L** - deletes the whole line

This set of actions covers all possible scenarios of line deletion I have encountered so far during heavy use of notepad++.

Comment: I know I'm a few years late, but wouldn't this macro work just as well with just DELETE instead of CTRL+SHIFT+L as the last command? If I understand you correctly, you have already marked all the text you want to delete with the first three commands.

Answer (score 11):

There is a shortcut in Notepad++ to delete a line: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`L` ..but this will only delete a single line.

Even if several lines are selected, it will only delete the line where the cursor is resting and not the highlighted lines.

So, the simplest way to delete a series of selected lines, you have to Record a Macro with these key shortcut combinations:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

followed by

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

This will first `JOIN` the selected lines and then `DELETE` the whole line.

This is **better** than using a combination of `CUT` and `DELETE` approach as mentioned above *(which i've tried)* because on some instances, it will also delete non-selected lines.

Answer (score 8):

As a non-macro alternative to @Jan Domozilov's answer, I followed these steps (using Notepad++ v6.5.1 (UNICODE)):

1. In the **Settings** menu, select `Shortcut Mapper`.
2. In the **Main menu** tab, set `Join Lines` (line 26) to `Ctrl+Alt+D`.
3. Click the **Scintilla commands** tab.
4. Set `SCI_LINEDELETE` (line 90) to `Ctrl+D`.
5. Close the window.

This allows you to perform the desired behavior with a small modification. You select your text, run the Join Lines command with `Ctrl+Alt+D`, release only the `Alt` key, and press `D` again to delete the text.

Answer (score 0):

One other simpler way is to use the `backspace` button after selection, this will replace selected line with backspace.

Comment: but then you need to select first then delete, which takes much more operations than a simple Ctrl+Shift+L

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to make Notepad++ behave more like Eclipse is to:

1. Map `SCI_SELECTIONDUPLICATE` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>)

[image]

2. Map `SCI_LINEDELETE` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>):

[image]

There is BTW a file called `shortcuts.xml` in the root of the installation folder where these changes can be found. I wouldn't rely on copying this file around however, since I've had problems with that approach installing the same shortcuts on more than one computer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CTRL+DELETE to delete the entire content of a line. Then all you do is use DELETE again to remove the line feed. If that is not enough for you, you can create a macro to do both actions.

As it seems to have stopped working in the latest version, I recommend you to use the Macro approach for the entire problem. Go to Macro, "Start Recording", then press "Home", "Shift"+"END", "DELETE", "DELETE", then go to Macro and stop your Macro. After that, go to Save Current Recorded Macro" and chose a name and shortcut, (e.g. CTRL+DEL). This reenables the shortcut for delete line.

Comment: `Ctrl+Delete` does not delete lines in Notepad++ for me (I have not remapped any keys other than `Ctrl+D`).

Comment: Which version of Notepad++ are you using? It's working on Notepad++ 5.8.2 under Win7

Comment: 5.8.7 (the latest version) on Win7 x64. Did you mean `Ctrl+Backspace`? (also doesn't work for me)

Comment: Ah, I just tested it with 5.8.7, and it didn't work either, let me see

Comment: I updated my Answer

Comment: Is there a way to make that macro work with multi-line selection? I already have single-line delete working, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Again, try the Macro. It's about the order of the keys. Assuming you have multiple lines selected means you go from, e.g. middle of line 1 to middle of line n. The sequence would be something like DEL, END, SHIFT+HOME, BACKSPACE, BACKSPACE. I hope that does what you want.

Comment: But that macro _performs_ the line selection. I just want a shortcut that deletes already-selected lines.

Comment: Uhm... if you have lines that are already selected, then just use DELETE. I don't quite get what you are getting at.
If you have the cursor position on a single line, the first shortcut works.
If you marked the entire line, just delete or backspace works
If you marked lines from middle of first line to e.g. middle of last, the second shortcut works.
If you have all the lines selected fully, Delete or backspace works again.
I don't know what you want except for that!

Comment: I don't want to have to select the entire line in order to delete it. As per the accepted answer, try `Ctrl+L` and see how it behaves differently.

Comment: I read the answer already, and I gave you a couple of different solutions as you didn't understand that the first one I gave you actually solved your problem as well (without scintilla, as I didn't know that one). But you accepted the other answer anyway, so there's no use in ranting around.

Answer (score -2):

CTRL+SHIFT+DELDETE works for me great to delete whole single line.

Comment: The OP wants to delete *all lines which are part of the currently selected text*. Your shortcut does only delete the first line of a selection.