# Same keyboard shortcuts for Notepad++ as in Eclipse

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, eclipse

As a regular Eclipse user, I find it very useful to adapt keyboard shortcuts to match the ones from Eclipse (such as this one: [How do I make Notepad++ delete lines like Eclipse does?](https://superuser.com/questions/258345/how-do-i-make-notepad-delete-lines-like-eclipse-does)).

However, manually changing all shortcuts is kind of tiring, and not always successful. So I wonder whether there is a config available that matches Eclipse shortcuts as closely as possible.

Comment: If the settings can be exported, if you're lucky maybe someone has already done this and shared the results for others to benefit.

Comment: They can be exported, but someone needs to make a mapping between the Eclipse keywords, and the scintilla/notepad++ keywords for those shortcuts. Not that complicated ultimately, but time consuming.

Comment: That's why I asked here before doing work that might already have been accomplished by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your current *Eclipse* keyboard-mapping
(choose from the menu: `Window > Preferences > General > Keys > [Export CSV...]`)
but the "*Commands*" there are not necessarily named the same in *Notepad++*.

Also, at the moment (v6.8.8), the *Shortcut Mapper* in *Notepad++* is lacking basic functionality
to sort or find existing actions and their related shortcuts,
not to mention saving/loading shortcut-mappings
(see this [discussion in the community](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11279/ctrl-shift-t-not-copying-current-line-to-clipboard/2) for example).

I have tracked my mapping-changes to be saved to this location (in Windows-7) -
`c:\Users\[my-user]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`
which gives me basic ability to copy my shortcut-mappings from one PC to another...